# Create large text field in Eloqua using REST API

Tags: rest, eloqua, large-text

I was trying to create custom object and corresponding fields in Eloqua. While creating a field with datatype `largeText` it throws validation error. I can create fields with datatypes like date, text, numeric etc. How can I create `largeText` fields?

This is my request body

```
{
    "type": "CustomObject",
    "description": "TestObject",
    "name": "TestObject",
    "fields": [
        {
            "type": "CustomObjectField",
            "name": "Description",
            "dataType": "largeText",
            "displayType": "text"
        }
    ]
}
```

Response is `[Status=Validation error, StatusCode=400]`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `"displayType":"textArea"`for creating largeText fields.